# Prompt user to select a date using MonthCalendar control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm writing a Winform application and at some point I would like to prompt the user to select a date from a calendar. So after browsing Google I figured I could use the MonthCalendar control to achieve that. Now here's what I have:

```
    MonthCalendar monthCalendar = new MonthCalendar();
    monthCalendar.Show();
```

The problem is that nothing happens when this code is reached. What do I do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: The MonthCalendar control should be added to its form controlscollection. It cannot be shown by itself

Comment: That explains it all. Thanks !

Comment: It is possible to create a small form with a `MonthCalender` control and a button to signal when a date has been entered. Then simply `ShowDialog()` on that form to prompt the user to enter a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic windows Forms handling.

A `MonthCalender` is a Control. You can't just show controls. Controls can only be shown on a `ContainerControl`. A `ContainerControl` is a Control that can hold other controls and take care that they are shown.

One of the most famous ContainerControls is the Form. In visual studio we usually use the designer to create the form and to put Controls on it.

Depending on whether you want your special MonthCalender only on one specific form or whether you want to reuse it on several forms, you must decide whether to put your MonthCalender on a Form, or on a User Control.

The nice thing about a user control is that you can use the designer in visual studio to drag and drop your special MonthCalender on any form.

But in the end, you have to put your MonthCalender somewhere on a form. Once you show your form the MonthCalender is shown with it.

```
public class MySpecialForm : Form
{
    public MySpecialForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The above is created by Visual Studio designer once you've added a form to your project: right click in Solution Explorer on the project and select Add - Windows Form

In the designer you select the Toolbox (Menu view Toolbox), on the Toolbox under `Common Controls` select the MonthCalendar and click on your Form where you want your Month Calendar to appear.

This is basic form designing. Once you've added your MonthCalendar, the code is created in `InitializeComponent`:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar monthCalendar1;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.monthCalendar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar();
    // 
    // monthCalendar1
    // 
    this.monthCalendar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(266, 83);
    this.monthCalendar1.Name = "monthCalendar1";
    this.monthCalendar1.TabIndex = 3;
```

You won't edit this file very often, it's much easier to use the designer.

Once you have your form and you want to show it, for instance after someone clicked a button on your main form:

```
private void OnMainFormButtonClicked(object sender, ...)
{
    using (var mySpecialForm = new MySpecialForm()
    {
        // if desired set some properties of the form before showing
        mySpecialForm. ...
        // show the form and wait for the result:
        var dlgResult = mySpecialForm.ShowDialog(this);
        // process the result
        if (dlgResult == ...)
        {
            ProcessResult(form.GetFormResult);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to do this. The code below uses a small `Form` with a `MonthCalender` and a `Button` created in the designer shown below.

[image]

This form is called by another “parent” form. When the user clicks the “Finished” button the parent form can get this date with the following public method `GetDT`located in the `FormCalender`. This code only gets the first selected date, however the user can select multiple dates. Also you can do any error checking if needed. Hope this helps.

Form 1:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FormCalendar fc = new FormCalendar();
  fc.ShowDialog();
  MessageBox.Show("User Selected Date: " + fc.GetDT.ToLongDateString());
}
```

FormCalendar

```
public FormCalendar() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.Close();
}

public DateTime GetDT {
  get {
    return monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
  }
}
```